# How to avoid content from wrapping/overlapping on 100% zoom?

Tags: html, css

[image: Here's a screengrab of how the tree is collapsing (chana should be connected to koppel)]I'm working on a family tree that I found [here](https://codepen.io/Pestov/pen/BLpgm). I've noticed as the tree grows it tends to collapse and overlap unless you zoom out at a specific level. Is there a way to either dynamically adjust the width of the content or is there a hackier way to resolve this?

I've tinkered a bit with a wrapper and adjusting the margins/widths but haven't had any luck so far.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x3dr8nL/3/).
Here is the CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;

  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;

  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover + ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover + ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover + ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover + ul::before,
.tree li a:hover + ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
.tree-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width: 900px;
  min-width: 950px;
}
.tree {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vw;
  padding: bottom 30%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 900px;
  min-height: 7000px;
}
```